Android Camerax video and audio are not aligned after pause, change camera selector while its paused, and then resume
I’m using CameraX to capture video, and I need to support a feature where the user can flip the camera while the video is paused, similar to Instagram and TikTok. My approach is to pause the video, switch the camera, and then resume recording. However, in the final saved video, the audio is out of sync with the video.
Note that The issue does not occur if I flip the camera directly without pausing the recording.
this is a snapshot of the CameraXPreview composable i use to render the preview of camerax
@Composable
fun CameraXPreview(
    onPreviewRefresh: (Camera) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    cameraSelector: CameraSelector,
    useCases: List<UseCase> = listOf()
) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val previewView = remember {
        PreviewView(context)
    }
    val previewUseCase = remember {
        Preview.Builder().build().apply {
            surfaceProvider = previewView.surfaceProvider
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(useCases, cameraSelector) {
        val cameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider.awaitInstance(context)

        val activeUseCases = mutableListOf<UseCase>()

        activeUseCases.add(previewUseCase)
        activeUseCases.addAll(useCases)

        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner,
            cameraSelector = cameraSelector,
            *activeUseCases.toTypedArray()
        )

        onPreviewRefresh(camera)
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { previewView },
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
}

